# Error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1, but data posted to server

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm getting this exception below, but the data is POSTed successfully.

```
Error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

Can anybody tell me what the issue is in this format?

```
{
   "trip_id":"9",
   "user":"admin",
   "vehicle_no":"Hr26Eu6341",
   "trip_action":" Start",
   "tripdetails":[
     {
         "item_name":"Tyre",
        "item_position":"Axel1-left",
       "tag_id":"E123dervceEp32432425"
      },
      {
        "item_name":"Tyre",
        "item_position":"Select position",
     "tag_id":"E123dervceEp32432424"
      },
       {
         "item_name":"Battery",
         "item_position":"",
         "tag_id":"E123dervceEp32432424"
      },
      {
        "item_name":"Battery",
         "item_position":"",
         "tag_id":"E123dervceEp3243222"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: May be due to json covered in double quotes. try to remove that using trimIndent() if you are using  kotlin.

Comment: Why is there a quote at the beginning? It's not valid json.

Comment: @JinalPatel I'm doing that by creating a model class

Comment: @f1sh that's inserted by mistake in the post only